# Dual wireless or wireless/wired on same Windows PC: One wireless shared access point with VPN and one wireless/wired normal (no VPN)

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, wireless-access-point

OK, so I was not sure how to title this, but this is what I am after, if possible?

OS: Windows 10 64 Bit

Firstly: I would like to setup a wireless access point through my wireless adapter on my desktop PC that connects to my VPN account. I would then use this for some of the mobile devices I have in the house.

Secondly: I would also like to connect to my wireless routers network that does not use the VPN and use this as the PCs network, not the VPN one mentioned above (As I understand it this network would also be visible to other mobile devices 
but would not be using my VPN account). Is such a setup possible on a single desktop PC (or any other single machine) and if so would I need two wireless cards? If that is not possible could I achieve the desired result with the second "normal" connection being wired instead of wireless? (I don't have to share that connection with mobile devices although it would be useful in an ideal setup.)

On a spare netbook I have managed to setup a wireless access point that shares my VPN connection and am able to connect to this with my various mobile devices. However the netbook clearly uses this same connection to connect to the internet through my router. However I think the netbook is about to die and I don't want to spend money on something that is only going to be used for this single purpose. Having said that, maybe I could use a raspberry pi setup to do the same thing. Although setting it up with the VPN AND the access point might be a bit tricky!

Any help much appreciated.

Chazg76